# Cordova, load the content of a page in a variable before displaying it entirely

Tags: javascript, php, cordova, optimization

I'm currently doing an app with cordova.
This app needs to load content from a server with a PHP page.
I load the content with an xmlhttrequest to do it dynamically. I have my HTML page structure with empty divs with ids, and then i fill them with a simple

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = ....
```

When the internet is slow/low or when the server is busy, it can take up to 3-4 seconds to load, and it makes an non-smooth effect of 'brutal appearing'.
I'd like to be able to load all the content from the server, add it to the `HTML` structure, and only then to display it on the app.
What are the best/most pertinent ways to do it?

Comment: Do you want to blur your page or show some sort of loading before everything else is loaded via AJAX ?

Comment: I assume you're using multiple XHRs to request the content from your backend?

Comment: Yes maybe a loader taking the whole page, during this time the content would be loaded, and then making the loader disapear to make the whole page appear but with all the content. And yes i'm using multiple XHRs requests, and this is not very 'beautifull' when the content appears !